# Run go fmt ./... got different behaviours on different OS

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, gofmt

When I run `go fmt ./...` under the root directory of the project in my vscode I got different formatting results on different OS:

`Windows`

```
import (
"github.com/abc"
"gotest.tools/assert"
"testing"
```

)

`MacOS`

```
 import (
"testing"

"github.com/abc"
"gotest.tools/assert"
```

)

Is this the expected behaviour for `gofmt` in different OS? If so, how do I config the code formatting rules in vscode to make it consistent?

Edit: I am using the same version of Golang on both OS.

Comment: Are you using the same Go version in both OS?

Comment: yes I am, it's go version go1.13.5

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely you have different versions of gofmt on different platforms. Another option - different set of commands.

You can try to run the command like this:

```
go fmt -n ./...
```

It should print details of `gofmt` utility calls. You can diff outputs from different platforms.

Based on my past experience VSCode didn't seem reliable and I had to switch to GoLand.

Comment: I am using the same version of go on both os, indeed GoLand removes a lot of headache :)